# Many to many bidirectional mapping in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have the following JPA entities.
A profile have many users and a user have many profiles:

```
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Profile> profiles;

    ...
}
```

On my application, when a user is [merged](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)), the profiles are updated on database.
However, when a profile is [merged](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)), the users are not updated.

Is possible to map my entities in order to make both sides merge their lists?
I am using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate.

Comment: Have you tried adding the cascade option CascadeType.ALL to both relationships?  Have it on the Profile->User relationship seems counter to your description stating that when merging profiles, users are not merged. Could it be that you aren't maintaining both sides of your relationship?

Comment: It can also be only CascadeType.MERGE

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried this solution, but it doesn't work. Probably it is another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Profile` entity is ownind side or relationship. It's up to it, to manage relationship, so in order to update `User` you'll have to update `Profile` too or make manual SQL calls.

[Java Specification for JPA 2.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) says that:

> • For many-to-many bidirectional relationships either side may be the owning side

So if you'd like to make both entities editable from both side, remove `mappedBy` element and assigne necessacy cascade. But I'm not sure it works in Hibernate (didn't try actually), see this docs on mapping, there's no information about m:m without owning side: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional

Otherwise, you may need to iterate through collection in `Profile` entity and then change them. For example:

```
for( User user : profile.getUsers() ) {
    user.setSomething(.....);
}

session.merge(profile);
```

Changing List to Set might be needed in order to avoid Hibernate's delete and reinsert, described here: http://assarconsulting.blogspot.fr/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html

Also, don't forget about `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods override